# Multiple If statement with Picklist values

Tags: formula

I have a formula date field that says

```
IF Portfolio = Interfaces 
AND
ISPICKVAL Status = AGREED
AND
ISPICKVAL Action= Reminder, then Date -28
ISPICKVAL Action=Chaser 1, then Date + 14
ISPICKVAL Action=Chaser2, then Date +42
```

This is set up like this:

```
IF(
    AND(
        Journal_for_Article_use__r.Portfolio__c  = "Interfaces",
        ISPICKVAL( Status__c , "AGR - Agreed to submit")
    ),
    CASE(
        TEXT( EA_Action__c ), 
        "Submission Reminder", (Expected_Submission_Date__c - 28),
        "First Submission Chaser", (Expected_Submission_Date__c + 14),
        "Second Submission Chaser", (Expected_Submission_Date__c + 42),
        Null
    ),
    Null
)
```

I have been asked to also add in the following.

```
IF Portfolio = Interfaces
AND
ISPICKVAL Status = INVITED,
AND
ISPICKVAL Action=Invite 1, then Otherdate + 28
```

The first section has been working fine, populating the formula field with Date -28, +14, +42. I now need to add in Otherdate +28 if the the status is Invited and Action is Invite 1 and cannot work out how to do it. I keep getting various errors, any idea how I merge the additional IF part into what I have already got please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd place the next if statement where the last null is right now. However, since we're here, we may as well optimize the rest of the formula, too. We can make it far more legible by doing this:

```
IF(
  Journal_for_Article_use__r.Portfolio__c  = "Interfaces",
  IF(
    ISPICKVAL(Status__c , "AGR - Agreed to submit"),
    CASE(EA_Action__c, 
      "Submission Reminder", (Expected_Submission_Date__c - 28),
      "First Submission Chaser", (Expected_Submission_Date__c + 14),
      "Second Submission Chaser", (Expected_Submission_Date__c + 42),
      Null
    ),
    IF(
      AND(ISPICKVAL(Status__c, "Invited"), ISPICKVAL(Action__c, "Invite 1")), 
      Expected_Submission_Date__c + 28, 
      Null
    )
  ),
  Null
)
```

Comment: Great, thanks very much, that worked, I just needed to remove the last ' ,Null ) '